# HQL query just does not fly with uniqueResult()

Tags: hibernate, hql

Hi I am trying to retrive a simple object from a db via its password hash and username combination ....

```
username = request.getParameter("username");
password = request.getParameter("password");

// Converting request password to hash
String passwordHash = SecurityUtil.convertStringToSHA1(password);


Session hs = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
hs.beginTransaction();

//query for a single result of matching username with password
//Query hquery = hs.createQuery("from User where id = :id");
//hquery.setParameter("id", 33l);  <- THIS QUERY WORKS

Query hquery = hs.createQuery("from User where password = :password and userName = :userName"); //<- password is a sha1 hash in the db
hquery.setString("userName", username);
hquery.setParameter("password", passwordHash);

User user = (User)hquery.uniqueResult(); //<- Always NULL WHY There should be a unique result.
log.info("UR: "+username);
log.info("PR: "+passwordHash);

if(user!=null) {
    //never reached
    log.info("UDB: "+user.getUserName());
    log.info("PDB: "+user.getPassword());

} else {
    always reaches here
}
```

Any Ideas? Or does that mean that there are no uniqueResults?

My sha1 hashes are not salted, however the password hashes are generated from a random string using apache commons which should be more or less collision free ...

Further it is my first time doing hibernate stuff so I might be in the wrong somewhere ...

Comment: What database are you running on? Turn on SQL logging with `hibernate.show_sql=true` and `hibernate.format_sql=true` in the hibernate configuration and check the SQL query you get. Make sure the password hash passed to the query is really the same like the one in the database (maybe this is a string escape issue).

Comment: yeah I have been thinking about escape issues thanks for the heads up on the logging .... I'll try that. I am running on mysql ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I know now where all went down the drain. I have jaspy string encryption enabled on these fields. Due to the random salt it is obvious that these fields in a WHERE clause just do not fly ... :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting null it means that no matching record was found.

There could be some problem with your password hashing.  You could take the password value from the database - hard code that value and test the hibernate query.  If that works you can then check why your input password is different.

You can also log the hashed password and check if it matches the value in the db. Also check the user name - case sensitive, leading / training spaces etc.

Comment: Well see the other query, where I get the User by id works just fine ... if I extract the password then and compare it to the request password it also equals ....

Comment: Then the problem should be with the userName.  I am pretty sure it is an issue with the input parameter - the query is fine.

Comment: If I just leave in the password on the second query I am also not getting any result, this is really strange. By id it works very well, I am sure I have no duplicate hashes in the db, because there is only one result?!?!